# Broken TeXLive update

Tags: texlive, polyglossia, bugs

I've just updated my TeXLive 2023 installation (with the `tlmgr update --self --all` command) and it appears to be broken. Specifically something in the polyglossia package. I have these lines (headers) in my document:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{czech}
\setotherlanguage{esperanto}
\setotherlanguage{english}
```

and they are causing the following error:

```
! Use of \__prop_put_linked:wnnN doesn't match its definition.
<recently read> \xpg@alias@keyvals@english@american 
                                
l.132 ...lias@values{english}{variant}{us}{american}
```

and when I choose to ignore it I get this on the very first page of the produced PDF (with LuaLaTeX):

[image]

When I comment out the line with otherlanguage english (esperanto is OK), the error disappears. Note that the page number in the right top corner is also an error.

I hope TeXLive people read this as I do not know where exactly should I report this besides this site. The bug must be pretty recent as I do update my TeXLive installation quite regularly.

Comment: see https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/626 for a workaround.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, it works. Won't it break the compilation though on machines where the latest update was not run yet? I cannot test it right now.

Comment: Problem confirmed. Thanks for the pointer, @UlrikeFischer. Just noticed the problem this morning.

Comment: predefining the prop won't do harm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the comment from Ulrike Fischer.